# BackgroundTransferRequest connect external power error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I use `BackgroundTransferRequest` class to download mp3 files in my wp8 app. Some of my files are over 100mb, so because of that I set `transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.None;`. However, transferstatus method still returns me external power message.
If you look at line 12 in code you can see that i set TransferPreferences as None

Here is my code to download mp3 file:

```
private void download_Tap_1(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (transferFileName != null)
            {
                Uri transferUri = new Uri(Uri.EscapeUriString(transferFileName), UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                BackgroundTransferRequest transferRequest = new BackgroundTransferRequest(transferUri);
                transferRequest.Method = "GET";
                string downloadFile = transferFileName.Substring(transferFileName.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
                Uri downloadUri = new Uri("shared/transfers/" + downloadFile, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
                transferRequest.DownloadLocation = downloadUri;
                transferRequest.Tag = downloadFile;
                transferRequest.TransferPreferences = TransferPreferences.None;

                try
                {
                    BackgroundTransferService.Add(transferRequest);
                }
                catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
                {
                    // TBD - update when exceptions are finalized
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to add background transfer request. " + ex.Message);
                }
                catch (Exception e2)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Unable to add background transfer request."+e2.ToString());
                }
                transferRequest.TransferStatusChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transfer_TransferStatusChanged);
                transferRequest.TransferProgressChanged += new EventHandler<BackgroundTransferEventArgs>(transfer_TransferProgressChanged);



            }
            else
                MessageBox.Show("select an mp3 file to download");


        }

        private void ProcessTransfer(BackgroundTransferRequest transfer)
        {
            switch (transfer.TransferStatus)
            {
                case TransferStatus.Completed:
                    if (transfer.StatusCode == 200 || transfer.StatusCode == 206)
                    {
                        RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId);
                        processresult.Text = "";
                        download.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                        lnk = new linkname();
                        URLListBox.ItemsSource = lnk.obj();

                        using (IsolatedStorageFile isoStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                        {
                            string filename = transfer.Tag;
                            if (isoStore.FileExists(filename))
                            {
                                isoStore.DeleteFile(filename);
                            }
                            isoStore.MoveFile(transfer.DownloadLocation.OriginalString, filename);
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        RemoveTransferRequest(transfer.RequestId);

                        if (transfer.TransferError != null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show(transfer.TransferError.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case TransferStatus.WaitingForExternalPower:
                    WaitingForExternalPower = true;
                    processresult.Text = "Waiting For External Power";
                    break;

                case TransferStatus.WaitingForExternalPowerDueToBatterySaverMode:
                    WaitingForExternalPowerDueToBatterySaverMode = true;
                    processresult.Text = "Waiting For External Power Due To Battery Saver Mode";
                    break;

                case TransferStatus.WaitingForNonVoiceBlockingNetwork:
                    WaitingForNonVoiceBlockingNetwork = true;
                    processresult.Text = "Waiting For Non Voice Blocking Network";
                    break;

                case TransferStatus.WaitingForWiFi:
                    WaitingForWiFi = true;
                    processresult.Text = "Waiting For WiFi";
                    break;
            }
        }
 private void transfer_TransferStatusChanged(object sender, BackgroundTransferEventArgs e)
        {
            ProcessTransfer(e.Request);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh286419(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CommonDevelopmentTasks)

If the file to be transferred is larger than 100 MB, set the TransferPreferences property of the transfer to None. If you do not, the system will automatically change the transfer settings to this value, meaning that the transfer will only proceed when the phone is connected to external power and has a Wi-Fi connection.

[image: Look at the Last Paragraph in Image]